# How retrieve org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection in JUNIT test from Context

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, jboss, jndi

I'm trying to grab a WrappedConnection in a Junit test class in order to test some DAO functionalities.

I have methods like this

```
public static List<Top5TermFact> getTop5TrendsForPeriodAndAnalysisRule(long arId, String date,  long analysis_type_id ,WrappedConnection  connection)
```

So my test class has his method **setUpClass()** that tries to grab connection to the datasource in this way:

Here the imported classes:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource;
```

Here the method code:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
    try {

    // Create initial context
    System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.NamingContextFactory");
    System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jboss.naming");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
    ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
    ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

    // Construct DataSource
    MysqlXADataSource pool = new MysqlXADataSource();
    pool.setURL("jdbc:mysql://192.168.xx.xxx:3306/db_name");
    pool.setUser("root");
    pool.setPassword("password");
    ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/social_coop", pool);

    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context webContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

    DataSource ds = (DataSource) webContext.lookup("jdbc/social_coop");

    con = (WrappedConnection)ds.getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this return an exception:

```
$java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection cannot be cast
to org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection at
it.netseven.socialproxy.test.TrendAnalysisRelationsFiller.
setUpClass(TrendAnalysisRelationsFiller.java:92)
[...]
```

so the problem is at this line:

```
con = (WrappedConnection)ds.getConnection();
```

Any Ideas?
Tnx

Comment: Why do you depend on it being a `WrappedConnection` and not just a `java.sql.Connection`?

Comment: yes i need a WrappedConnection cause the methods have this signature

Comment: Then ask yourself why does methods have that signature, and not the more general `java.sql.Connection`. On the face of it, it sounds like a poor design to require an implementation-specific class/interface, especially as its api only adds a small number of methods that you usually won't need.

Comment: I'm agree with you about the code refactoring. 
But the problem IS  that I have to test many classes that  always have this signature. 

I should refactor all methods.
I'm asking if there is a pratical solution to test these classes. 
This solution i think involves to create a WrappedConnection.

Comment: I think it will be pretty hard, maybe you should check if JBoss itself has unit tests involving a WrappedConnection and see how they obtain it.